# How many values allowed in "In Clause" statement in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

Is there a limit on the number of values that can be passed in the "In Clause" of Amazon Athena query?  Tried to look that up in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) but can not find any reference. Thank you.

For example
`Select * from tablename where columnName in (1,2,3..); -`

How many values allowed to be passed in the IN CLAUSE of the above statement?

Comment: There might be some hard limit somewhere, however, you should use your common sense on the readability of the code with too many of these values. I recommend to use a JOIN with a lookup table if you have too many such values. Your future self will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only limitation is the length of the query, which is limited to 262144 bytes (or characters):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html